# Using Object.create from inside class with this keyword

Tags: javascript

i have this simple class:

```
 function Page(u,o) {
   this.o = o;
   this.gen(u);
 }
Page.prototype = {
 gen:function(u) {
    if(u ==='index.php') new test(this.o);
 }
}
new Page('index.php',{data:"just for test"});
```

Is there a way to use Object.create(this); instead of new test(this.o); so that the test class can have access to this.o? and not spawn new instances of test every time? As you see i don't use var x = new ... because i don't need it.
test class just use the this.o to append some data in a div element, nothing is returned.
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use a class for `test` if it doesn't (need to) create instances.

Comment: Class test has many methods and needs to generate some custom forms, also there are many pages, each page is generated by a class like test, this was only a small example, i just need to pass this.o to the corresponding class without generating a new instance, this.o is a large array of objects and can get up to 100 Mb, i just wanted to pass only a reference to the new class without spawning a new variable containing this.o ...

Comment: What do you mean, "pass to class without an instance"? Do you need to create an instance or not? Should it be a static method rather than a constructor?

Comment: "*without spawning a new variable containing this.o*" - Huh? What's wrong with that? Notice that arrays are reference values, there won't be 100mb of data copied because of a function call.

Comment: No, it's not a reference to the variable. But if `x` contains an array, then `this.x` will contain the same array, and you can mutate it via both references.

Comment: I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a class, just make test a normal function (if it is not already) and drop the "new". For that matter, since it looks like you don't do anything with the `Page` class either, make that a straight function as well:

```
function page(u, o) {
  if (u === 'index.php') {
     test(o);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer my question ... is there a way to pass that object to a new class by reference or some other way so that the object is not duplicated, the object can get very large, also class Page and test have many methods and proprieties, and also there is a class like test for every page. This was just a small example to demonstrate what i want to achieve. Thank you

Comment: @Gabriel - Whenever you pass an object to a class or function it is passed by reference. No duplication.

Comment: so in my example if my test constructor looks like this: `function test(o) { this.o = o; } ` the this.o is a reference to this.o from my Page class? and if i change it inside test it will change inside Page too?

Comment: Nice, thank you for this. So the answer is that i don't need to use Object.create :)